# What is the HiveQL for obtaining day of week?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am selecting date from my table "tweets" as

```
select to_date(created_at) from tweets;
```

which gives me dates like,

```
2011-09-28
2011-09-25
2011-09-25
2011-09-24
```

However, I need to convert the dates into a day of week format,
1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

How do I achieve this?

Edit: 
I think I can get the day for a sample date as,

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2014-01-12','yyyyMMdd'),'u');
```

How do I incorporate this in my original query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`date_format(..., 'u')` for a date-like string/type gives Monday=1 and so on.

The other answer uses 'w' which gives the week in the year, which isn't what you want.

Your original query becomes:

`SELECT date_format(created_at, 'u') from tweets`;

See the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for all the options.

Answer (score 3):

If you have hive 1.2 this should work.  It is in the language manual.  I am running hive 0.13 so I can't test the date_format function but it should give you an integer from 1 - 7;

```
select cast(date_format('2015-04-06'),'w' as int) as DOW from table;
```

I tested this on hive 0.13:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015-07-06','yy-MM-dd'),'u') as 
   DOW from table;
```

This resulted in 1, so it appears to work.

Other options that can be used if the above fail is to:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015-07-06','yy-MM-dd'),'EEEE') as 
   DOW from table;
```

This will return 'Monday'

Additionally

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015-07-06','yy-MM-dd'),'EEE') as 
   DOW from table;
```

Will return 'Mon'

Then you can simply do a case when to change to integers.

```
case when DOW = 'Mon' then 1 
     when DOW = 'Tue' then 2
     -- ...
     when DOW = 'Sat' then 6
    else 7
end as day_of_week
```

Don't use this:

```
select pmod(datediff('2015-07-06','1970-01-04'),7) + 1 as DOW from table;
```

This returned 2, which is incorrect and has been suggested by others.